# Ajax not working in visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to do an ajax website, but my ajax is not working. I checked my GAC and system.web,extensions dll is available.
Why it is not working .? I am also not getting any errors. I tried many ways.
I wrote the below code to test ajax.

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JAvascript error that i got

```
  1.Type is not defined
    http://localhost:1467/testnew/Default.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d1.0.20229.20821%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3ac5c982cc-4942-4683-9b48-c2c58277700f%3ae2e86ef9%3aa9a7729d%3a9ea3f0e2%3a9e8e87e9%3a1df13a87%3a4c9865be%3aba594826%3a507fcf1b%3ac7a4182e
```

Comment: Is it because my dll (system.web.extensions) version present in the assembly is 3.5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure ajax 1.0.20229.20821 is registered on your machine before trying to use the controls

You can find it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861898(v=office.12).aspx